# Compilation error after upgrading to TypeScript 3.1.6 (or higher)

Tags: angular, typescript

During the upgrade to Angular 7 (in a hybrid project of AngularJS and Angular), TypeScript was upgraded to version 3.1.6.

A compilation error has occurred:

> TS2320: Interface 'SVGElement' cannot simultaneously extend types
> 'Element' and 'SVGElementInstance'.
>
> Named property 'getBoundingClientRect' of types 'Element' and
> 'SVGElementInstance' are not identical.

Tried to upgrade Typescript to the latest version (currently 3.5.3), and had the same error.

Any suggestions?

Do I have another npm package that conflicts with TypeScript? And if so, how can I know which package is it?

> Angular version: 7.2.15
>
> AngularJS version: 1.5.x
>
> TypeScript version: 3.1.x and higher
>
> rxjs version: 6.5.2

Comment: Are you using `SVGElement` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, in d3 charts (d3 version is 3.5.x). I can try to upgrade d3, but I think they have some breaking changes, so not sure it will be easy.

Comment: Are you using them in *your* code?

Comment: I'm using SVG, but not SVGElement as a typed object somewhere. I have no declaration of an object of type SVGElement in my code.

Comment: Radical approach - Have you tried removing node_modules folder and make sure you don't have multiple node_modules folders? You could even try removing package-lock.json. Try fresh npm install. Sorry this isn't a particularly technical answer but it might help?

Comment: It fails not only locally, but also in our build server. The build server works with the most updated package.json and does npm install, And also locally, I deleted node_modules and started npm install (no package.lock). The error is still there, both locally and in the build server.